# How to Remove Multiple Databases Marked with "Recovery Pending"

Tags: sql-server, delete

Recently I tried to clean my appilcations which used SQL database(s), therefore, the leftover databases are now marked with "Recovery Pending".

[image]

Right now I can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/delete-a-database?view=sql-server-2017) to delete them manually.

How do I remove all those DBs marked with "Recovery Pending" in only one action?

Comment: Drop database db1, db2, db3,...,dbN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the meta-data off your SQL Server (as seen in sys.databases) and that is indeed the DROP database command (which is performed by SSMS when you right-click and Delete). Either do them one-by-one, as in

```
DROP DATABASE a DROP DATABASE b
```

Or more then one at once, as in

```
DROP DATABASE a, b
```

You can also generate those DROP commands, such as:

```
SELECT 'DROP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name)
FROM sys.databases
WHERE state_desc = 'RECOVERY_PENDING'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Tibor.
Does it mean it is not possible to create a general script (without specifying each DB) such as DROPping all DB WHERE it is "Recovery Pending" ?

Comment: Oh, yes, you can generate the commands. See my addition above.